# Image data from database not showing in stimulsoft report in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I stored complete image physical path in database and when passed same path into stimulsoft report then it is showing in local development version as well as staging version. But in production version it is not showing. I created field img in stimulsoft designer as image... but is not working.! How to display it? Could you pls help on this.

Answer (score 0):

use an image control to load the image by physical address.then make an array of byte and send it to Stimulsoft.

it shows you how to set an array of byte to send to Stimulsoft:

```
dtModel.Columns.Add("Pic", typeof(byte[]));
```

How to add data:

```
byte[] img = Member.Image.Data;
```